# Iterating over a column to see check certain conditions in Bigquery

Tags: sql, loops, google-bigquery, iteration

I am using Big query to extract results from employee learning table. I need to figure out if an employee has completed a set of courses for a department. For example if an employee complete all of these three courses say, course 100, course 200 and course 300, they can be classified as as compliant else They are non-compliant. I have created a dummy example of how my data is structured, unfortunately due to organization policy I cant share more information.
Problem statement.
Say employee who has completed course 100,200,300 They are compliant in Bakery else they are non-complaint. Employee must complete all three courses to be compliant.

Employee who has completed course 100 and 300 They are compliant in Fruit & Veg else they are non-complaint. They must complete above mention two courses to be compliant.

Employee who has completed course 75,85,95 They are compliant in Grocery else non-compliant. Same here they must have done three courses so that they can be compliant.

Employee who has completed 101 and 102 They are compliant in Nighfill else non-compliant.

Please note employee must complete all the sets to be compliant in relevant categories

Employee course
1        100
1        101
1        200
1        300
1        300
1        400
2        100
2        200
3        100
3        200
3        300
4        75
4        85
4        95
4        105
4        115
4        125
5        200
5        200
5        100
5        100
5        100
5        300
5        300
6        100
7        100
8        300
8        200
8        100
8        101
8        102
9        100
9        200
9        300

[Structure of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLkOh.png)

I am still thinking about the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select Employee, 
  ifnull(array_length(split(string_agg(distinct if(course in (100,200,300), '' || course, null)))), 0) = 3 isBakeyCompliant,
  ifnull(array_length(split(string_agg(distinct if(course in (100,300) and not course in (200), '' || course, null)))), 0) = 2 isFruitVegCompliant,
  ifnull(array_length(split(string_agg(distinct if(course in (75,85,95), '' || course, null)))), 0) = 3 isGroceryCompliant,
  ifnull(array_length(split(string_agg(distinct if(course in (101,102), '' || course, null)))), 0) = 3 isNighfillCompliant,
from your_table
group by Employee
```

with output

[image]